# Custom arduino board

Tags: shields

Hey There Arduino Coders. I am a relatively seasoned C/C++ programmer. However, I'm still new to the Arduino Game. I'm coming here today to ask you guys a direct question that I couldn't find a direct answer for on google... here it goes:

Is it possible,(also practical) to create my own arduino board? after creating a prototype with an arduino uno and various shields?

In other words. Is it possible to shrink the arduino(make a custom arduino), and all of its shields on to one board? It seems rather large to have to lug around all of those shields and such. CHEERS!

Comment: What shields do you want? Depending on the shields you use, a better option might be to start by analysing how to reduce the shields, and then decide how to connect and control them.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking. An Ethernet shield.

Comment: It might help folks give a good answer if you update your question with the specific shields you'd like. So add Ethernet, and anything else you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a page about a [breadboard Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/breadboard) which is basically an Atmega328P processor (same as in the Uno, inter alia) on a breadboard.

[image: Breadboard Arduino]

---

Also a [wire-wrapped Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11109).

[image: Wire-wrapped Arduino]

---

You can go pretty minimalistic with a [ATtiny85 mounted on a button battery](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12769) like this:

[image: ATtiny85]

---

> Is it possible to shrink the arduino(make a custom arduino), and all of its shields on to one board?

Ah there you might be asking a bit much. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of shields people have designed for it. Certainly you can make up your own board to meet a specific purpose.

Comment: Hey thanks alot Pal ... This is helpfull!!!!!!

Comment: If the shield schematics of the shields you want to use are publicly accessible and you can get the parts, you should be able to build many of the available shields on a perfboard, for example

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.  You might start with the [Arduino to Breadboard Tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard) while defining your hardware requirement - for example, decide what voltage you are going to run at (and pick an appropriate regulator) and then decide if you can use the imprecise 8 MHz internal oscillator or if you need a more precise external resonator or crystal.

Once you have determined your required circuitry you can advance to making  circuit board, and possibly switch from the DIP version of the ATmega to a QFP package which is smaller and potentially ultimately easier to work with (for production you might even use a QFN, though that is a bit more challenging to solder by hand).  You may also want to look at what package technology your peripheral chips come in.

Do note though both that you can buy smaller premade Arduion-compatible PCBs, and that there are other chips which are worth considering for a permanent project, some with Arduino compatible libraries available, and some without.

Comment: Could you name some of those "other chips?" I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. It can be as simple or as complex as you wish :)

http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-your-own-Arduino-board/